# Is it smart to publish tab-activity-based app to Android 4.0+ devices?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabactivity, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-tabactivity

I have a `TabActivity-based` project which I want to publish to Android 4.0+ devices as well. When I load it with SDK 4.0+ library, I receive a warning `"android.app.TabActivity" is deprecated`.

We all know that this is due to the fact that fragments are advised for any 3.0+ app, thus making `TabActivity` deprecated.

Now, is it smart simply to include Android 4.0+ devices to use this app? What are the hidden bombs/bugs?

I am asking this as moving to fragments would require a complete app redesign and 2 months of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, i personally too have used TabActivity where it suited perfectly for the requirement in one of the cases... Fragments adds on the concept and provides more advanced and diff features, but yeah it works very differently from TabActivity.

Android recommends Fragments to more of support high variation in screen sizes , but switching from TabActivity to Fragments just to replicate same feature won't be good idea ...

Comment: I did not understand what you did to your app. did you upgraded it to 4.0+ devices and it worked perfectly or you switched to fragments?